# Installing Ubuntu 14.04: GUI goes crazy

Tags: system-installation, lightdm, gui

So when I try to install Ubuntu on my workstation from USB and the GUI finally pops up either from **try Ubuntu** or **install Ubuntu** the windows just go nuts, they are different colors, scrambled and absolutely unreadable. I have a picture here to clarify. 
This is from trying Ubuntu and attempting to open a terminal:

[image: terminal]

I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a `vty` and enter

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

but upon restart the problems persist. I’ve been able to install Ubuntu before albeit with a few problems but ever since I swapped out my 2nd graphics card to an ATI as well, I’ve had this problem.

Some thoughts I had were to maybe download the minimal server version and then put a Desktop environment on that, but I kinda consider that the easy way out

Is there maybe some sort of thing I can edit at grub by pressing `e` I believe that contains the quiet no splash that I could possibly modify as some sort of workaround?

Comment: @Mudit: Please don't just improve the formatting;  improve the spelling as well.  Please [review my edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/584517/revisions) so you can improve yourself... (installing a spell checker in your browser helps a lot)  **;-)**  (and Ubuntu is with a capital first letter, BTW)

Comment: **Gr4cchus:** yes, you can set the `nomodeset` parameter there, then update your drivers and then remove the same parameter at next boot.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions: Installing from usb 2.0 port and running on an ATI graphics card. For Bios i had iommu enabled and usb legacy support on

Possible Bios factors to consider: iommu, usb legacy settings and keyboard mouse port emulation settings?

Power on the computer and spam the key needed to access the boot menu which in my case is `F12` and select the boot device. **Note**: in more modern motherboards two options may appear with one containing something about UEFI in which case I had problems with and would urge against in this situation.

Momentarily a screen will appear with an icon of a keyboard at the bottom, press the down arrow key when seen however spamming the down arrow key beforehand may be wise. Choose your language and `Enter` then press `F6` and arrow key select `nomodeset` then back out of the menu and choose to either `install ubuntu` or `try out ubuntu`.

In my case after installation my graphics card was not running properly so i had two things to do. I `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and found the line containing `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"` and removed `nomodeset`

Next i went to `system settings`>`software updates` checkmarked `proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)` then closed the window to reload. Navigating back to that window I select the `Additional Drivers` tab to install proprietary drivers then revert back to open source.

**END Notes**: There are other methods for moving around this process such as [manually editing the grub boot options](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) at grub pressing `e` on the selected target. Or a similar method but dfferent work around [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/boot-parms.html) manipulating boot parameters to launch things such as "noninteractive" mode which would not start X. But the method I choose is in my opinion quicker and more fool-proof. I hope this was helpful and successful.